# Crop pdf generated with gnuplot

Tags: software-recommendation, pdf, gnuplot

I am generating a graph with gnuplot and then, I need to crop a part of it as a pdf or high-quality image to be used with LaTeX.

I have tried generating the graph as a pdf and then cropping it but it cannot be transformed with tools that would serve for other pdfs. I can open it with Evince but not with Okular or Pdf-Shuffler. I have also tried with Krop and Briss without sucess. Pdfcrop returns the following error:

```
!!! Error: Cannot find PDF header of 'my_graph.pdf'
```

I can take a screenshot of the pdf but I can cannot save it as a pdf and if saved as an image, the quality is not good enough.

I have found [an old pdf-shuffler error](https://sourceforge.net/p/pdfshuffler/bugs/22/) that refers to pdfs that contain only an image. I wonder if my problem is related because the pdf includes only the graph. However, this problem has been solved and was only related to export, while I am unable to import.

I am using Ubuntu 17.10.

Is there any tool I can use to crop a gnuplot-generated graph to pdf (or high-quality image)?

How is this pdf file different from others of the same format?

Comment: You can crop the image directly inside a LaTeX `\includegraphics` environment, using the `trim` and `clip` parameters. See for example [Crop an inserted image?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/57418/crop-an-inserted-image)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My file was not recognized by the cropping tools because I had not set up gnuplot properly.

As I had been working with eps before, I was using `set terminal eps` instead of `set terminal pdf`. After changing this, I can work normally with the pdf file.

Answer (score 0):

You can save your graphic in EPS format, which provides a high quality image. So, you can use GIMP to manipulate the graph with good resolution and export it as EPS or PDF.

Comment: Saving eps from image editors usually just saves embedded jpg.